# Confused about Node.js mysql error handling

Tags: mysql, node.js, try-catch, throw

First of all, I'm fairly new to node.js and its way of handling errors still feels foreign to me. I'm just really struggling to wrap my head around it.

I'm trying to write a simple program in node.js using express that receives mySQL queries over the network, executes them, and returns the result. That part is already functional, but the program crashes if the client sends a query that results in a mySQL error. The offending code block is as follows, inside of a normal (as in not async) function:

```
try {
    connection.query(queryFromClient, function (error, result, field) {
        if (error) {throw error} else {
            response.send(result[0]);
            response.status(200); 
        };
    })
} catch (error) {
    response.send("Query error");
    response.status(422);
    console.log("Query error from client");
    }
});
```

As you can see, the query *should* throw an error if something goes wrong, and that error is wrapped in a "try" statement. Properly formed queries work okay, but malformed queries cause the program to crash on the connection.query line despite the error handling. If, for instance, I run `SELECT column FROM badtable`, where badtable doesn't exist in the database, I get no response on the client end and the following error in the node.js log:

```
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
^

Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'mydb.badtable' doesn't exist
```

Comment: The query is asynchronous. The `try/catch` has already exited when the error is thrown.

Comment: Use the promise version of `node-mysql`. Then you can use `await`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an error function:

```
(err, req, res, next) => {
   return res.status(err.statusCode).json({ message: err.msg })
 }
```

And instead of throwing the error pass it to the "next" function

```
if (error) {
    next(error)
    return
}
```

Comment: So the next question would be how to catch an JS / TS error WITHIN the `function (error, result, field)` function? Eg. when you wrote code that is trigger an undefined runtime error. Since this is a callback method. I now need to write try/catch within each of those methods to prevent my app/server getting crashed.